# Enigmail: don't decrypt automatically

Tags: encryption, thunderbird, enigmail

I am using Icedove 17.0.10 (Thunderbird) with Enigmail 1.5.1.

It used to be, that when the option `Automatically decrypt messages` was disabled, any encrypted email was displayed in the encrypted form. First when I clicked on `Decrypt` was I asked for a passphrase and the email was decrypted.

This still works for the received encrypted emails, but not for sent emails.

For some reason, when I go into my `Sent` folder and select an encrypted message which I have sent previously, I am always asked for the passphrase. This is extremely annoying.

Is there any way to disable this?

I suspect this has changed after some update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in enigmail, which has alredy been reported: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=732067